# how to split this string of HEX bytes

Tags: python, python-3.x

i have the following string of hex bytes from a smart meter:

```
'~\xa0\x1e\x03\x00\x02\xfe\xff4\xca\xec\xe6\xe7\x00\xc4\x01A\x00\x02\x04\x12\x00\x05\x11\x01\x11\x01\x11\x00\xc7\x11 ~'
```

I want to separate them in a list and then pass them to decimals or int. The .split() python function won't work, any ideas?

thanks!

Comment: `str#split` will split on the space character by default. Use `list('your string')`.

Comment: thanks a lot, its working now, :3

Comment: A string is an iterable sequence of characters. It's possible that whatever you want to do with the list of individual characters, you can do with the string itself. `map(int, s)` and `map(int, list(s))`, for example, do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert a string to a list of ascii values with `ord`.

```
values = [ord(c) for c in data]
```

Although, depending on what you want to do, you might not even need to cast your data as a `list` since a `str` is already iterable.

Instead, iterate over your characters and recover their value. Here is a simplified example.

```
dt = '\xa0\x1e\x03\x00\x02\xfe'

for x in map(ord, dt):
    print(x)
```

#### Output

```
160
30
3
0
2
254
```

Comment: coool, i will give it a try next monday, thanks for the suggestion good developer senior:D